# Issue With Zero Rate Tax

Tags: checkout, tax, vat

I am having an issue with Magento's tax calculations, I inherited this website and had to upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9.3 (the client says that this wasnt an issue before the upgrade)

There are 20% tax rules setup for VAT/EU countries which seem to work fine. The issue arises when a customer from a 0% tax country try to checkout, where the grand total will include 20% tax.

For example:

> SUBTOTAL (EXCL. TAX)   £83.33
>   SUBTOTAL (INCL. TAX)   £83.33
>   **GRAND TOTAL    £99.99**

Any ideas on how I can sort this, admin has all prices added with Tax included if that helps.