# Can't make zero TAX rate

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-calculation, magento-1.9.3.2

I'm facing a problem with setting a zero tax rate for some countries. Regardless that the catalogue prices are set to show including tax, whenever a quote is for 0% tax countries, grand total excluding and including tax are exactly the same and includes tax.

Someone has already similar issue but no answers [Issue With Zero Rate Tax](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204878/issue-with-zero-rate-tax) so maybe I'll have more luck.

Here are some screenshots of Magento settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Quote for order with standard 20% TAX:
[image: Quote for order with standard 20% TAX]
Quote for order with **0% TAX**:
[image: Quote for order with **0% TAX**]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple but perhaps not the answer you want.

You've got your products stored as price inc vat.

So zero rate the prices will come through as they are. Because you are applying zero rate.

If you store your prices ex vat and update the settings accordingly you will get desired result.

However I'm fully aware this may not work for you or the client.

Comment: Thank you. I did check that by setting that catalog prices excluding tax and now calculations are correct. But is this the only way to have this sorted?